# Silex: Separate javascript and twig template

Tags: javascript, silex

I would use an external javascript file to use it into my twig template.

I hade read [here](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/assets.html) that I should install asset so this is how I have done:

*accueil.twig*

```
{{ app.request.basepath }}.javascript.js
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Créer un utilisateur</title>

        <style>
            #plateforme{
                width:1200px;
                height:600px;
                border-style:solid;
                border-color:blue;
                background-color:white;
            }
        </style>
        <body>

            {{ asset('javascript.js') }}
            <div  id="plateforme" onclick="Changecolor()"></div>


        </body>
```

But javascript code doesn't work, only if I put all code into twig template.

I'm using Silex framework.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "doesn't work"? Does the mark-up not get written into the HTML doc? Does the JS error? Does it just not do anythign? Does the request error?

Comment: yes the javascript don't show anything, but when I copy paste it in the twig template it does.

Answer (score -1):

Now it works , no assets needed , just

```
<script src="templates/javascript.js"></script>
```